# Java - wait in for loop until method finishes, then continue

Tags: java, loops, timer, synchronization, jlabel

I need to run through a `for` loop where the text of a `JLabel` is set with the counter variable `i` and after that a `Timer` method is called. I now want the loop to wait until the method finishes.

Code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        labelNr.setText(Integer.toString(i));
        startTimer();
    }           
}
```

Because what it does now is that it instantly sets the text of the `JLabel` to 5, because it runs through the loop, but starting the timer just in the first loop.

I want the text of the `JLabel` to be 1 for the first loop, then call the Timer method, then 2 for the second loop, again Timer, 3 for the third loop and so on.

**It basically just needs to wait until the `startTimer()` method has finished its execution. I know that synchronized is the possible solution, but I do not know how to implement it properly...**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

OK, since I want a quick and dirty answer, it was voted down. So how about this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    changeLabelAndExecuteTask(1)
}

public void changeLabelAndExecuteTask(int i){
    labelNr.setText(Integer.toString(i));
    startTimer(i);
}
public void startTimer(final int i){
    //start a timer here
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){ 
        @Override 
        void run(){
            methodTimerCall(i)
        }}, 0);
}

public void methodTimerCall(int i){
    //execute things here
    if(++i < 6){
        changeLabelAndExecuteTask(i);
    }
}
```

## forget the under part

You can add a static boolean and reset it value by the timer:

```
bool waitForTimer = false;
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        waitForTimer = true;
        labelNr.setText(Integer.toString(i));
        startTimer();
        while(waitForTimer){}
    }
}
public void startTimer(){
    //start a timer here
}

public void methodTimerCall(){
    //execute
    waitForTimer = false;
}
```

Comment: can you explain why the minus feedback?

Comment: `bool` is not a type, it is not static like in the explanation (which is also lacking), it is never set to `true` and busy-waits are expensive.

Answer (score 0):

An effective approach could be to put the code inside the for loop in a separate method, and have the 'startTime()' method call this method at the end of its execution.This way you guarantee that it runs exactly when the method is finished, rather than at an arbitrary time (I.e. with Thread.sleep();)